# Selenium Timeout with Heroku

Tags: python, selenium, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I intend to create an app with Selenium (python) hosted on Heroku, that uses discord in the browser

```
import os

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

def sampleCode():
    # CHROMEDRIVER_PATH is a config var in Heroku, set to '/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver'
    b = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), chrome_options=chrome_options)
    

    b.get('https://discord.com/channels/@me')
    wait = WebDriverWait(b, 10)

    # Find the email input part, and enter the email set as a config var in Herkou
    email = b.find_element_by_name('email')
    email.send_keys(os.environ.get('username'))

    # Find the password input part, and enter the password set as a config var in Herkou
    password = b.find_element_by_name('password')
    password.send_keys(os.environ.get('password'))

    # Clicks the login button
    b.find_element_by_css_selector('selectorGoesHere').click()

    # At this point, the browser should have filled in and submitted the login form (https://discord.com/login) and moved into the main application (https://discord.com/channels/@me)
    # b.get('https://discord.com/channels/@me') redirects to https://discord.com/login btw

    settings = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'selectorGoesHere')))
    settings.click()

sampleCode()
```

I get an error from Selenium:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

The error message refers to when I defined the settings variable
This means that Selenium could not find the element that I looked for (which is a settings button)

HOWEVER, when I run this same code but without the stuff for Heroku (so no chrome_options stuff, and `b = webdriver.Chrome()`, it works perfectly. This leads me to believe that it might have something to do with --headless or the other args.

All of the Heroku stuff that I set up followed this tutorial (you can read the blog post or watch the video): https://www.andressevilla.com/running-chromedriver-with-python-selenium-on-heroku/

Other imports include:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import threading
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

I want to reemphasize that everything works without the `chrome_options` and Heroku when I run `python Main.py`

Comment: You ever figure this out?  I have the same issue. Works fine on most things but my heroku instance times out every time no matter what combination of arguments I use. Tried window size with and without headless and other permutations.

Answer (score 0):

[google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless) opens the *Browsing Context* with a reduced [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

You need to explicitly increase the *Viewport* using the argument `"window-size=1400,600"`

As an example, the default *Viewport* for Headless Google Chrome browser is `1400,800`

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.headless = True
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  print ("Headless Chrome with default window-size")
  size = driver.get_window_size()
  print("Window size: width = {}px, height = {}px".format(size["width"], size["height"]))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Headless Chrome with default window-size
  Window size: width = 800px, height = 600px
  ```

---

Where as in specific usecases you need to override the default *Viewport* for Headless Google Chrome browser with a custom *Viewport* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.headless = True
  options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  print ("Headless Chrome with custom window-size")
  size = driver.get_window_size()
  print("Window size: width = {}px, height = {}px".format(size["width"], size["height"]))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Headless Chrome with custom window-size
  Window size: width = 1400px, height = 800px
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, even after changing the viewport size as you suggested, I still get the same error.

Comment: @NicholasPfeiffer Don't set the viewport to `1400x800` blindly but set it to the default value which you use otherwise.

Comment: Did you get a solution for it? @NickPfeiffer